# Deploy Grails to AWS error 404

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a grails application. I don’t have the War file. I only have the folders and the files. 
I am trying to install it and I am facing problems. The steps I am using are:

- I am creating a zip file that contains the application(files and folders)
- I am going to Elastic Beanstalk wizard and I am creating new environment using TomaCat 7. I am using all the default configurations.
- I upload the zip that contains the application when the wizard ask for that. 
  Finally  the wizard informs me that the application installed correctly, but when I am trying to View running version I am taking the error HTTP Status 404.
  //Edit
  // The error:

> Error Compilation error: startup failed: General error during semantic
>   analysis: unable to locate the java compiler com.sun.tools.javac.Main,
>   please change your classloader settings
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: unable to locate the java compiler
>   com.sun.tools.javac.Main, please change your classloader settings     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavacJavaCompiler.findJavac(JavacJavaCompiler.java:190)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a war file out of the grails project by running `grails war`.

This will pack your application in a nicely deployable war file (with all the dependencies).

After that you'll be able to deploy it to AWS.

To run the command you need to open up the Grails Command prompt.
Right click on the project -> Grails Tools -> Grails Command Prompt.

Type `war` in the opened pop-up window and you'll get a packaged war file.

I've attached the screen shot as well

[image: how to open a grails command prompt]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where should i write this command? I have download groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.0.0.M3-e4.2-win32

Comment: Thank you. I take this error:Error Compilation error: startup failed:
General error during semantic analysis: unable to locate the java compiler com.sun.tools.javac.Main, please change your classloader settings
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: unable to locate the java compiler com.sun.tools.javac.Main, please change your classloader settings
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavacJavaCompiler.findJavac(JavacJavaCompiler.java:190)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavacJavaCompiler.compile(JavacJavaCompiler.java:49)

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME defined and pointing to a valid JDK? It looks like the compiler cannot found the tools.jar file which contains the JDK compiler.

Comment: Are you sure that you're pointing to the JDK and not the JRE. Please look at this nabble thread and confirm: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-run-app-error-on-Quick-Start-instructions-td4302496.html

Comment: The values are JAVA_HOME   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 and GRAILS_HOME C:\grails I have set to this folder grails. Also i have stoped the iis from running. Also i have set to path variable %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin

Comment: Furthermore I run from cmd “java –version” and I get the version of java I run. I run also the command for grails and I get the version I have.

Comment: try to run cmd "javac -version"

Comment: it gives me the version of javac 1.7.0_25

Comment: post the whole trace please

Comment: Please check my edit. I have the whole error that i take when i try to run the application Locally. With Grails-Groovy Tool Suite

Comment: just a wild guess - JDK is not visible, as it is located in a folder with a space in its name. Also are you running Oracle jdk?

Answer (score 1):

If a normal VPS is an alternative for you, I could help post instructions for you on how to set it up.  It should be easy.

- install tomcat
- install mysql
- setup database
- upload war or upload sources and build inside server

Comment: The strange is that I take the same error on eclipse.  I do the following when I try to run it locally. 1) Open eclipse. 2)Click import. 3)Select the application folder and click ok. 
Then I try run the application but I take the same error on dashboard. (I don’t find any sql file. I only have an xls).

Comment: can you share some screen capture for me to have a look on the error on your eclipse?